# Segregate salary and name from single column and calculate their salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i/o:

```
col_details
Sam100
Ram200
Sam1000
Ram50000
Aryan450
```

o/p:

```
col_name col_salary
Sam       1100
Ram       50200
Aryan     450
```

Comment: Please indicate which database this is for, not just 'sql' - I suspect SQL Server given your previous question but please confirm.

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the DML you are trying to use. If you need to hire a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Answer (score 3):

PATINDEX is supposed to find the first location of a given expression.  In this case, a number.  So, you split based on where that number is found.  SUBSTRING on the name takes any text before the number,  SUBSTRING after the name takes any text starting with the number.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(COL_DETAILS, 1, patindex('[0-9]',col_details)-1) col_name,
    SUBSTRING(COL_DETAILS, patindex('[0-9]',col_details), len(COL_DETAILS)) col_salary
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: When i run your script in sql i am getting errors

Comment: made a recommended change...whats the error?

Comment: The erros is:Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 1):

Pls find the below script

```
Declare @EmpData AS TABLE (col_details Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @EmpData
SELECT 'Sam100'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ram200'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam1000'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ram50000' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aryan450'

SELECT EmpNAme,SUM(Sal) AS col_salary
 FROM 
(
SELECT col_details,
SUBSTRING(col_details,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col_details))AS EmpNAme,
CAST(SUBSTRING(col_details,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col_details), LEN (col_details)) AS INT)AS Sal FROM @EmpData
)dt
GROUP BY EmpNAme
ORDER BY EmpNAme DESC
```

Result

```
EmpNAme col_salary
------------------
Sam     1100
Ram     50200
Aryan   450
```

View demo [Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4566e/4)

Comment: thanks .. can not upvote you as I dont have good reputation. Please upvote my question